# Automatically Mark Up HTML Text

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, string

I am hoping to find a way to automatically mark up an HTML document based on text matches.  I have a directory containing several hundred short HTML documents, the contents of which are individually included (via PHP) in a base_document.html depending on the value of a variable taken from the URL, as so:

```
<?php include $_GET['id'] . ".html";?>
```

If the included HTML document contains a specific word, e.g. "dangerous," I would like to automatically format it with a particular markup; for example:

```
<strong>dangerous</strong>
```

Is there already a particular library or function in PHP, JavaScript, and/or CSS that provides this kind of functionality?  Or would I need to write my own code to achieve my purpose?

Edit:  There would be a long list of target words and associated markups, so I assume I would need to refer to a custom dictionary residing in either a file or database.  E.g.,

```
"dangerous",bold
"important",style:color=red
"hungry",em
"hot",strong
```

Comment: Use a DOM parser to parse HTML and wrap words with tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example, you must adapt to your case:

```
<?php

$data[] = 'dangerous,bold';
$data[] = 'important,style:color=red';
$data[] = 'hungry,em';
$data[] = 'hot,strong';

$string = 'They are dangerous and hungry but I think that is hot talk about this.';

for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
  $line = explode(',', $data[$i]);
  $string = str_replace($line[0], "<{$line[1]}>{$line[0]}</{$line[1]}>", $string);
}   

echo $string;
?>
```

Output:

```
They are <bold>dangerous</bold> and <em>hungry</em> but I think that is <strong>hot</strong> talk about this.
```